# Configuring CK Editor plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, ckeditor, grails-plugin

How do we configure the CK Editor plugin in Grails? I'd like to use a couple of add-ons and customise the skin (theme) as well. The documentation by Stefano Gualdi, which seems to be the most prominent material, isn't too helpful. Also, I did find a builder which will let us customize (http://ckeditor.com/builder), but I couldn't find anything similar for CK Editor in Grails.

Also, the builder gave the impression that I customize my package according to my needs, download it, and copy it onto the location in Grails. Is that how it's done, or do we start off with the basic build only, and somehow connect with the add-ons?

In particular, I'm looking for options like Auto-save, File upload, etc. I'm guessing add-ons are the way to go.

Comment: http://www.craigburke.com/2013/07/15/ckeditor-in-grails.html maybe this is usefull?

Comment: I did check out this link. This is for incorporating the basic Ck Editor in our GRAILS project. I want to know how to configure it, so as to be able to use the variety of add-ons and skins which seem to be available in the Builder.

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration

Comment: Again, how does this configure add-ons, skins,etc? I have tried a number of these links. I was able to do basic changes to the configuration, like modifying the templates given,etc using these links, not what I'm asking for.

Comment: Thos options are called plugins

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/addon/autosave

Comment: I've gone through these links. If you've used any of them, tell me how you configured it.

Comment: i havent, im just trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CKeditor repo in grails site old one and is of version 4.4.1.0 and it needs upgrade. If you need to add to plugins in your grails project. This is what I have to add custom config. I had referred to some site. But I forgot. Anyways, here's my workaround. Sorry for not having line breaks, as stackoverflow seems to ignore it.

1. Place ckeditor `compile ":ckeditor:4.4.1.0"` under `BuildConfig.groovy`.
2. Place your resources under `/web-app/ckeditor/plugins/` and `/web-app/ckeditor/skins/`. In my case `divarea, lineutils, dialog` folders are placed in the `plugins` and `office2013` in the `skins` folder.
3. Place ckeditor specific config in `Config.groovy`. Code underneath is from the default ckeditor plugin with `config` part modified.
   Sample code:

   ckeditor {
       config = "/ckeditor/ckeditorconfig.js"
       skipAllowedItemsCheck = false
       defaultFileBrowser = "ofm"
       upload {
           basedir = "/uploads/"
           overwrite = false
           link {
               browser = true
               upload = true
               allowed = ['jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png']
               denied = ['html', 'htm', 'php', 'php2', 'php3', 'php4', 'php5',
                         'phtml', 'pwml', 'inc', 'asp', 'aspx', 'ascx', 'jsp',
                         'cfm', 'cfc', 'pl', 'bat', 'exe', 'com', 'dll', 'vbs', 'js', 'reg',
                         'cgi', 'htaccess', 'asis', 'sh', 'shtml', 'shtm', 'phtm']
           }
           image {
               browser = true
               upload = true
               allowed = ['jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png']
               denied = []
           }
           flash {
               browser = false
               upload = false
               allowed = ['swf']
               denied = []
           }
       }
   }
4. Create custom static resource in your view to mimic javascript file.
   Here's mine located in `/views/staticjs/ckeditorconfig.js`. Sample Code for this file:

   <%@ page contentType="text/javascript;charset=UTF-8" %>
           CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'divarea', '${resource(dir: '/ckeditor/plugins/divarea/')}' );
           CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'lineutils', '${resource(dir: '/ckeditor/plugins/lineutils/')}' );
           CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'dialog', '${resource(dir: '/ckeditor/plugins/dialog/')}' );
   CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ){
                    config.extraPlugins = 'enterkey,divarea,dialog;
                    config.skin = 'office2013,${resource(dir:"/ckeditor/skins/office2013/")}';
                    config.removePlugins="elementspath,resize";
                    config.resize_enabled="false";
                        config.toolbar_custom = [
                   [ 'Styles', '-', 'FontSize','-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline']
                   ]
           };
5. Create an entry in UrlMappings.groovy for this file.

   `"/ckeditor/ckeditorconfig.js"(view:'/staticjs/ckeditorconfig')`

I hope you can configure your required plugins afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear! The problem that I (and a couple of others, from the looks of it) was facing was that the default config file wasn't working with Firefox for some reason. It started working after I created another config file and routed control there.